# Передача списка значений в БД Sqlite Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я в цикле формирую список значений для записи в БД (Sqlite):

```
def dynamic_data_entry(*values):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", values)
    conn.commit()

for line in fin:
    for i in line:
        if i == '.':
           isreal = True
        if i != ' ' and i != '\n':
           value += i
           continue
        if value != '':
           if isreal == True:
              value = float(value)
           else:
              value = int(value)
           isreal = False
           values.append(value)
           value = ''
        else:
           continue
    dynamic_data_entry(values)         
    values.clear()
```

Текст ошибки:

```
 c.execute("INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", values)
    sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 10, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Comment: Покажите пример строки в переменной `line`, при котором наблюдается ошибка.

Comment: почему вы распаковываете в параметре функции dynamic_data_entry и не распаковываете в execute?

Comment: для чего делаете постоянный commit, тоже не очень понятно, скорость добавляния очень сильно снижается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Проблема решена, в функции `dynamic_data_entry(*values)` я изменил аргумент `*values` на `values` и всё заработало, это видимо тонкости языка Python(программировал на нём очень мало), но я примерно понимаю в чём была проблема. Спасибо за ответ Dmitry Erohin.
2.) Спасибо Igor (`для чего делаете постоянный commit, тоже не очень понятно, скорость добавляния очень сильно снижается. – Igor 16 часов назад`). Внёс предложенные исправления, это существенно сказывалось на скорости работы.